# Manipular y guardar un gif utilizanto wolfram-mathematica

Tags: gif, wolfram-mathematica

Tengo el siguiente código para representar una función:

```
Manipulate[
     ContourPlot[(0.98)*s*(x*y*z)
     , {x, 0, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", PlotLegends->Automatic, AxesLabel->{x,y}]
,{z, 0, 1,Appearance -> "Open"},{s,0,1,Appearance -> "Open"}, ContentSize -> 550]
```

Me gustaría poder manipular una serie de valores cualquiera de `s` y `z` (entre 0 y 1) y guardar la manipulación en un gif. Soy nuevo utilizando el lenguaje.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, recomiendo guardar tus imágenes en una table (`Table[]`). No me queda claro si quieres variar `s` y `z` simultáneamente, o fijar uno y mover el otro.

Supongamos que son independientes, entonces puedes generar muchas gráficas, digamos que variando cada una entre [0,1], con intervalos de 0.1:

```
minS = 0;
maxS = 1;
intervalosS = 0.1;
minZ = 0;
maxZ = 1;
intervalosZ = 0.1;
```

Tomando esos 'parámetros', podemos hacer una tabla con todas las imágenes (121 en total, en grupos de 11 en este caso, una iteración varía `s` y otra `z`).

```
tablaImgs = Table[ContourPlot[(0.98)*s*(x*y*z), {x, 0, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
   ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
   FrameLabel -> {x, y}, ImageSize -> 550], {s, minS, maxS, 
   intervalosS}, {z, minZ, maxZ, intervalosZ}];
```

Y de esa tabla (te recomiendo ver qué hay en cada imagen, porque yo no sé qué orden buscas tú), se pueden hacer diversos GIF. Como ignoro qué orden requieres, yo aquí voy a animar el segundo gráfico de cada uno de los 11 grupos de imágenes (sin otra razón más que aparentemente el primer elemento siempre está todo azul, entonces aquí yo escogí el segundo):

```
imgsAnimadas = Table[tablaImgs[[a]][[2]],{a,1,Length[tablaImgs]}];
```

Guarda el GIF de esta lista particular:

```
Export["MiGIFanimado.gif", imgsAnimadas]
```

Resulta en (puedes abrir la imagen para ver la animación):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos